# Generalized Dirichlet Distribution vs Inverted Dirichlet Distribution vs Grouped Dirichlet distribution

Tags: distributions, generalized-dirichlet-distribution, grouped-dirichlet-distribution, inverted-dirichlet-distribution

**Question:** What are the main differences and similarities of the Generalized Dirichlet Distribution, Grouped Dirichlet distribution, and Inverted Dirichlet Distribution? And when should one be preferred over the other?

*(References are welcome. Somehow I was not able to find any comparisons of the distributions although I looked in a few textbooks and searched for material online. I was able to find the descriptions of each distribution separately, but what I am interested in is the comparison.)*

Comment: Could you provide the definition of the three distributions? This will help to answer the question